# Difficult Probability mixed with combinatorics problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Melinda has three empty boxes and $12$ textbooks, three of which are mathematics textbooks. One box will hold any three of her textbooks, one will hold any four of her textbooks, and one will hold any five of her textbooks. If Melinda packs her textbooks into these boxes in random order, the probability that all three mathematics textbooks end up in the same box can be written as $\frac{m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m+n$.

I was wondering if I could use stars and bars to solve this. There are $$\binom{12}{3}$$ Ways to arrange the three textbooks anywhere.

Case 1: They all end up in the box which can hold maximum of $5$ books. The answer says the ways to arrange are:

$$\binom{5}{3}$$

But the question I want to ask is:

> Why are they looking for how many ways there are to arrange the books in the box? I mean the spaces are: $B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4, B_5$ What is the need to look at how many ways the books can be arranged in the spaces?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'spaces' in this context. Btw, there are $12$ textbooks, $3$ math-textbooks and $3$ boxes. How come that there are $5$ 'spaces'?

Comment: @drhab, $5$ spaces in the box which can hold $5$ textbooks.

Comment: I see. Well, there are $12$ spaces in total and $\binom{12}3$ ways to place the math-books on $3$ of them. Each of these arrangement has equal probability. In $\binom53$ of these arrangements they end up in the box that holds $5$ textbooks.

Comment: @drhab, I posted this comment on your answer as well. What does $$\binom{5}{3}$$ Mean here?

Answer (score 3):

If there are $\binom53$ arrangements such that the math-books end up in the box that can hold $5$ books then the probability of this event is $\binom53\binom{12}3^{-1}$.

Likewise you can find the other probabilities: $\binom43\binom{12}3^{-1}$ and $\binom33\binom{12}3^{-1}$ for ending up in the box that can hold $4$ and the box that can hold $3$ books respectively.

So we end up with probability: $$\left[\binom33+\binom43+\binom53\right]\binom{12}3^{-1}=\frac{15}{220}=\frac3{44}$$
for the event that the math-books end up in the same box.

Comment: (+1) What does $$\binom{5}{3}$$ In the context actually mean? I didn't understand this actually. $$\binom{5}{3}$$ To me, I thought means in the five spaces available in the third box (can hold 5 books max), $\binom{5}{3}$ is the number of ways the arrange the $3$ books within the $5$ spots? Is this what it means? Or does it mean how many ways there are to choose the $3$ math textbooks from $5$ textbooks that can go in the box?

Comment: It stands for the number of ways $3$ spots can be picked out of the $5$ spots in the box. The selected spots are meant for the math-books. So your first mentioned notion is correct.

Comment: thanks! But why is the probability determined by the number of ways the spots can be chosen?

Comment: Because each of these ways has equal probability to occur. In that case if there are $n$ ways and an event takes place at $s$ of these ways then $\frac{s}{n}$ is the probability of that event. Here if there are $\binom{12}3$ ways to place the math-textbooks in the $12$ boxes and in $\binom53$ of these ways the math-textbooks end up in the box that can hold $5$ books then the probability that this event occurs is $\binom{5}3\binom{12}3^{-1}$.